# Change displayed month in jQuery datepicker, depending on another datepicker instance

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two datepicker fields, one is '**start date**' the other is '**end_date**'.

I would like to have the feature that, after user selected '**start date**', then the '**end date**' calendar should show by default the month contain the '**start date**'.

Vise versa, if user first select **end date**, the calendar for the **start date** should show the month contain selected **end date**.

how to implement inside jQuery datepicker? What's the datepicker options I should defined?

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({
  //which datepicker options should put here?
})
```

Comment: You might want to check out the semi-official jQuery UI [date range picker](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/). It's not exactly what you're asking for, but it might be a good alternative. It offers some functionality that's kind-of nice.

Comment: I will have a look at semi-official one, but now I would like to make this based on what I have :)

Comment: Try to use the "onSelect" function to change the "defaultDate" option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sets the default date of the other calendar as you want. If a date is already selected it doesn't change it.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", dateText );
        }});
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", dateText );
        }});
    });
```

If you want to force the other date picker to reset it's already selected date to the other calendars month, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "setDate" , dateText )
        }});
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate" , dateText )
        }});
});
```

Comment: sometimes the datepicker1 sets it's value to the currentDate, there's probably some assignation during the "set defaultDate" event

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to avoid user selecting `end-date` less then `start-date` and `start-date` greater than `end-date`.

```
    $("#start_date").datepicker({
        defaultDate: '-7d',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function (dateStr) {
            $("end-date").datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate') || '-1m');
        }
    });
    $("end-date").datepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function (dateStr) {
            $("#start_date").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate') || 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to save the selected date in `datepicker1` and, before show the `datepicker2`, set mannually the same date. So, `datepicker1.date == datepicker2.date`. I hope it helps you.

```
var dateselected = '';

$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    dateselected = dateText;
  } 
});
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
  beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    if(dateselected != '')
       $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker('setDate',dateselected);
  } 
});
```

You can see it running in the following link: http://jsbin.com/orizi4